# Why php5-fpm is depending of a "sury.org" version of php5-common?

Tags: apt, php

I try to install `php5-fpm` package but I have this information:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-fpm : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.7+dfsg-1+sury.org~quantal+1) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is full terminal output:

```
root@myserv /home/pw # sudo apt-get install php5-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
```

and:

```
root@myserv /home/pw # sudo apt-get install php5-fpm --fix-missing --fix-broken
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-fpm : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.7+dfsg-1+sury.org~quantal+1) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to install `php5-fpm` package through `aptitude` which resolves all the dependency problems,

```
sudo aptitude install php5-fpm
```

To install aptitude,

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error :(

Comment: same error occurs on running which command?Din the first command purge the php5-common package?

Comment: Yes, I run all your commands and after `sudo apt-get install php5-fpm` I have the same error/information

Comment: Now try this command  `sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude install php5-fpm`

Comment: did you are using `natty`(11.04) version?

Comment: If no,then disable proxy by selecting the proxy method to none.

Comment: Thank you! `sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude install php5-fpm` this works